# Dropbox permissions on ggplot2 saved charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, dropbox

I have an R script that I run on a regular basis with launchd (OS X 10.8.3 Mountain Lion), calling it with `Rscript myscript.R`

The script creates generates some ggplot2 plots and saves them into my Dropbox folder with the `ggsave()` function.

The problem I am having is that the saved plots don't sync to Dropbox properly - they get the little blue "synching" icon and never upload.  I can fix it by going into the Dropbox preferences and using "fix permissions" but I'd like to have it so that when I output the files they will synch without any problems.

What could be the problem?  If I run through the same script manually in RStudio, the plots save properly and synch to Dropbox without this happening.

Comment: What user does launchd run under? It's probably not you.

Comment: Ahh it's running as root... that may be the reason

Comment: Can you identify the error in console?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this was indeed a file ownership issue.  I had launched set up to run my script as root, and because the files had the root owner, the .png charts saved from ggplot2 would not sync to Dropbox, which is under my user account.

The odd thing is that my script also output .html files, which do sync even with the root owner.

When I changed it to run under my user name, the output of the script synced to Dropbox as it should.  Now, my only problem is that launchd will not run the script if I'm not logged in :/